# Transactions in IBM WebSphere

Tags: java, transactions, jms, websphere, jta

I want to use transaction in my webapp that runs on IBM WAS 7.
I've got 2 databases and JMS (mq), and it will be great to rollback them all together.
What the best practice to do that? 
Should I need to use 3d party JTA libs (like spring.tx or JOTM) or WebSphere already has this stuff inside? May be I dont need JTA at all?
And can I use WAS transactions without Spring or EJB? Just ibm libs that WAS already include.

Comment: Which version of Websphere Application Server you are using?

Comment: Why would you need JTA, Spring, EJB to "rollback them alltogether"? There is no problem of rollback. Commit is an issue.

Comment: I have Websphere 6, and Websphere 7. Marcin Płonka, of course commit them all together too. People did a lot of frameworks for transactions, I thought that it could be nice, to config webphere transaction manager in a right way. And in code just mark some of my methods.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use JTA Transaction for the purpose you describe.

Websphere supports **2-phase commit** transactions which seems to be the case for you.

However you need to create an **XA Datasource** for each of the Databases in order to have a [Global Transaction](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wasinfo/v8r0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.websphere.nd.multiplatform.doc/info/ae/ae/cjta_glotran.html) that will handle Database and JMS Resources.